# Reading specific MKV metadata from avconv

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, matroska, libav

I want to extract a specific piece of metadata from an MKV and use it as the filename of a converted file.

Example, if I run `avconv -i MyFile.mkv`

I get the following output

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'MyFile.mkv':
  Duration: 00:06:49.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9062 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 409.057000
    Metadata:
      title           : UK Songs
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : x264   1280x720   Bitrate=7843 kb/s
...
```

I want `Metadata -> title` - in this case "UK Songs".  I can't see any information about reading this specific metadata and using it as a variable in the [libav documentation](https://libav.org/avconv.html)

At the moment, I'm converting the file using

`avconv -i MyFile.mkv -acodec copy MyFile.ac3"`

This gives me a file named "MyFile.ac3", whereas I want a file named "UK Songs.ac3"

Comment: I'm unsure why you tagged this as [ffmpeg](http://superuser.com/tags/ffmpeg/info). `ffmpeg` and `avconv` are not equals and are different enough to warrant separate tags unless you are using both.

Comment: "Cunningham's Law" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just output title metadata:

```bsh
echo "$(avconv -i MyFile.mkv | grep '^\s*title\s*:' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*title[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]//')"
```

And this will do the conversion to the filename you want:

```
avconv -i MyFile.mkv -acodec copy "$(avconv -i MyFile.mkv | grep '^\s*title\s*:' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*title[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]//').ac3"
```

At least it does here on my OS X using Bash, not 100% sure if sed differs significantly on your Ubuntu.

Comment: avconv outputs to stderr, so for grep to work, it needs to be `avconv -i in.mkv 2>&1 | grep -m 1 ...` (the `-m 1` makes sure it only grabs the first result)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title with `ffprobe` alone (no `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc needed). I'm highly doubtful that `avprobe` can.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title -of default=nw=1:nk=1 in.mkv
  UK Songs
```

You can adapt this example into your favorite script/shell/command.